# save a counter to the aux file and read it later

Tags: counters, auxiliary-files, page, lastpage

I would like to write a counter to the aux file and then read it back when compiling the tex file for the second time. Basically, I am trying to write a command that has the same logic as the LastPage package. I want to save a certain pagenumber, and then refer to it on the pages before it.

Comment: Use `\label{mypageref}` and `\pageref{mypageref}`.

Comment: Actually, you need `\refstepcounter{mycounter}` before `\label`.  It sets `\@currentlabel` (and possibly `\@currentlabelname` and `\@currentHref`) locally.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism for this is already in place.

When you do `\label{whatever}` next to a word that you know will fall in the page you want to refer to, you just say

```
\pageref{whatever}
```

to print the page number wherever you desire.

The purpose of `lastpage` is to place a suitable `\label` without user intervention, but of course it can only work for referring to the last page.